# Google sheet: Is it safe to use custom function to get a cell value when the sheet sometimes need time to calculate the value?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I use a form to collect user input into a spreadsheet. Then I use some formulas to process the data in another sheet. I noticed sometimes when I open the sheet, there will appear a progress bar and some value in the processed sheet takes a while to show up. Before the progress bar finished, the values are blank.

Now I am using some custom function to get data from this sheet when user submit the form. What concerns me is if the value takes sometimes to show up, will my custom function, which executes right after user submit the form, get blank values?

Comment: The answer to your question - Yes, if the formulas do not have time to update the information on the sheet before you read the data, the result will be empty

Comment: There are several solutions, but it's hard to tell which one to apply because you don't have an example:
1) [SpreadsheetApp.flush()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app?hl=en#flush()) - apply this method before you read the data from the sheet
2) You're using a script anyway - so maybe you should calculate using a script instead of formulas in a spreadsheet. This will be much faster
3) You can try replacing thousands of identical formulas with a single array formula, which will work much faster

Comment: If you want this to run when the user submits the Form, I'd suggest using an [onFormSubmit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/spreadsheet-trigger-builder#onFormSubmit()) trigger instead of a custom function. Have you thought of this?